When comparing two dataframes in an azure function app, I receive this error- valueerror: the truth value of a series is ambiguous
I have some logic here that I'm using to iterate through dataframes. My goal is to iterate through all of the rows in one dataframe and compare that row against every row found in another dataframe. So, where "code" matches in the two dataframes I want to

Transform df2's code to equal  df's"code2" value instead.
Also transform df2's "IsForm"'s value to equal df's "IsForm"'s value.

If there is no match between code values on the two dataframes, transformation on df2 should not take place
Here is a small example of what I'm doing (this example works as expected):
df_dict = {'code':[388,289,200], 'code2':[1,2,3], 'IsForm':[1, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)

df2_dict = {'code':[388,289,200], 'IsForm':[0, 0, 0]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2_dict)

for ind in df.index:
    for ind2 in df2.index:
        if df2['code'][ind2] == df['code'][ind]:
            df2['code'][ind2] = df['code2'][ind]
            if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1:
                df2['IsForm'][ind2] = 1

The above example behaves as expected and transforms df2, but when working with actual data that I'm pulling from a couple tables and stuffing them into the dataframes, I receive this error, triggered by if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1::

exception: valueerror: the truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I can run this code locally, even extract the actual data I'm using from an azure sql database and it performs just fine, but I receive this error when the code is run in the cloud. Regardless, how do I solve this issue and is there any better way to achieve my goal here? I'm sure this solution is quite slow so I'm looking to improve that if possible.

"My goal is to iterate through all of the rows in one dataframe and compare that row against every row found in another dataframe". Compare them how and do what following the evaluation? Please [edit] your question to clarify the goal and expected output. Maybe also add an example of what should happen to rows (values?) that have no match between both dfs. What should happen to them? By the looks of it, you simply want to get df2[['IsForm', 'code2']] for each value in df2['code'] that has a match in df['code'] (but what if it has multiple matches?).

@DasariKamali instead of the dataframes being built by dicts it's something like df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * from table ", conn) for instance

@ouroboros1 yes I will edit my question to try and be more clear. if there is no match for that row, then I don't want anything to happen. how could there be multiple matches per row?

@ouroboros1 you were spot on in your evaluation, that's basically what I want to happen. If I'm thinking through this correctly, there is not a case where IsForm and the code2 would have multiple matches with a code. They will stay static per code associated

"How could there be multiple matches per row". Well, perhaps you could have two rows with the same 'code' value in df? At any rate, one typical cause for the error with df['IsForm'][ind] == 1 is that df['IsForm'][ind] is not returning a scalar, but a pd.Series, meaning that df has duplicate index values. But in order to properly evaluate the error, you would have to add a [mre].

@ouroboros1 I see, good question, there should only be 1 row associated with a code in df. Duplicates/multiple matches shouldn't exist. Interesting... well that table only has 1 row in it.

@ouroboros1 Unfortunately I have provided the closest thing I could to a minimal reproducible example, the error only exists when it's run by my function app in the cloud   and I've no reason why it's only happening there. I guess I'm looking for a possible alternate solution to the way I'm doing this now to see if the cloud will end up liking that solution better- I don't doubt that there is a better way of doing this regardless

Problem is that your code is not reproducing the error you receive with your actual data. So, something in it differs from its representation as df. Now, one such difference might be duplicate index values. E.g. I can make your code throw the error by using df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict, index=[0,1,0]). Of course, that's just a guess. But you don't have to guess, you need to debug your code :). Use some try / except statements and print df['IsForm'][ind] where appropriate: what do you see? Without locating the issue, any success with an alt solution is just going to be pretty random.

Yeah.. it's just very unusual. Even when I test it on the same data that my function app is having trouble with, it performs fine locally. Hmm, I'll keep trying to debug and hopefully have an update..

This part in itself will be a problem for 'large datasets'
for ind in df.index:
    for ind2 in df2.index:

This will create an O(n^2) complexity, which is and will be inefficient for large data in the long run. In your dataset the resulting error from if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1: might be indicating your dataset might not be fully structured as the sample dataset might be, so it may be returning a series rather than a single value as you want and that's why you get exception: valueerror: the truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
I would maybe use a single loop if both df's are equal in size (rows) like;
for ind in df.index:
   match_index = df2[df2['code'] == df['code'][ind]].index
   df2.loc[match_index, 'code'] = df['code2'][ind]
   if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1:
       df2.loc[match_index, 'IsForm'] = 1

Possible Solution: Merge the two dataframes on 'code' since your logic '

where "code" matches in the two dataframes I want to'

merged_df = pd.merge(df2, df[['code', 'code2', 'IsForm']], on='code', how='left', suffixes=('', '_df'))

Replace:
if df2['code'][ind2] == df['code'][ind]:
        df2['code'][ind2] = df['code2'][ind]

With:
df2['code'] = merged_df['code2'].fillna(df2['code']) 

same thing since you wil be updating df2 code only where there are a match else return original code
replace this part:
if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1:
            df2['IsForm'][ind2] = 1

with this part:
df2['IsForm'] = merged_df['IsForm_df'].where(merged_df['IsForm_df'] == 1, df2['IsForm']) 

In the long run the cost for merging the dataframes will be more bearable than the time complexity for a nested loop to iterate a dataframe

Such a merge might well work, and if so, will obviously be way better than a nested loop (just about any solution not using such a loop will be faster). But when you say "in a small dataset if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1: might work but pandas may be treating if df['IsForm'][ind] as a series rather than a single value as you want", you make it seem as if 1) that might happen at random, or 2) the size of the dataset matters. Neither is true, of course. Rather, I'd say, the error is a hint that the OP has a dataset that is not fully structured the way the OP thinks it is.



I'd say, the error is a hint that the OP has a dataset that is not fully structured the way the OP thinks  >> it is this is 100%  true, I had really tried to replicate that error but nothing, I have edited the answer,
Edit:
your dataset the resulting error from if df['IsForm'][ind] == 1: might be indicating your dataset might not be fully structured as the sample dataset might be, so it may be returning a series rather than a single value as you want and that's why you get exception: valueerror: the truth value of a series is ambiguous. use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().


